# The best way to display item's specification on item page for Google's better indexing

Tags: php, indexing

As I've heard site with more Google's index has more chance to show better results

i wrote my own CMS
my site structure like this
index.php, itempage.php and insertitem.php [and some anothers that not important]

users insert item by fill insertitem.php
those items shows on index page
visitor user select item from index page and its call itempage.php?item_id=[id]
and this page show item properties

But this will cause the number of pages indexed to be limited to several numbers, despite the large number of products.
This method leads to a small number of Google indexes
no problem?
It is not better to create a html page in the server side when inserting the items's properties by using the php code. To be indexed by Google separately?
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Google and other search engines have no issues with query strings and consider them to be different pages

Comment: @John Conde thanks but google bot only indexed 9 pages for my domain without query string pages